# Signer Gem and XMLSEC format - Adding Modulus and Exponent in xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xmlsec

I'm trying to get a xmlsec format with signer but I can´t create this.  I'm trying to create this format:

https://gist.github.com/patojimenez/84d22500611620b8b3bebea30243108a

Has anyone worked with this format?  I tried with the single format:

https://github.com/ebeigarts/signer/blob/01f65278db8852be3f4a28c7f10a2cced966f506/spec/signer_spec.rb#L91-L110

However, the format is very different, and only returns **X509Data** tag information.  I need **KeyValue** tag information.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [signer gem](https://github.com/ebeigarts/signer) seems to be suited only for signing messages **over the [SOAP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security)**, which has its own format. You seem to want singing a plain XML document, for which you might try these gems instead:

- https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/xmlsec
- https://github.com/wonnage/xmlsec-ruby

Both of them are wrappers around the **[xmlsec library](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/index.html)**, which works with the format you desire.